# Writing to a Protobuf CodedOutputStream

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers

I'm having issues writing to a CodedOutput Stream using the Objective-C port of Protobuf:

```
    POPMessage_Builder* builder = [[POPMessage_Builder alloc] init];
    [builder setPayload:@"Hello, world!"];
    POPMessage* message = [builder build];

    NSOutputStream* rawOutput = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToMemory];

    PBCodedOutputStream* os = [PBCodedOutputStream streamWithOutputStream:rawOutput];
    [message writeToCodedOutputStream:os];
    [os flush];

    NSData* data = [rawOutput propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];

    NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

At the end data is always null. I've tried writing various things to it, but it seems like the PBCodedOutputStream never seems to write to the nsoutputstream.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spent a couple hours debugging this exact issue.

```
[rawOutput open];
```

From Apple Notes:
The stream must be opened before it can be used.

P.S. - How very helpful of them to design an in memory stream that must be opened before use. And the streamError property is null when you try to write to an unopened stream.